# How Many Values Can Be Represented With n Digits in Hexadecimal Systems?

Tags: binary, hex

I have `n = 7`. How many different values can be represented using 7 digits in  In Hexadecimal Systems?
I approached it this way:

I set each bit of the `7` to be equal to `1`. Therefore the highest number I get is `111 1111 =  16^0 + 16^1 + 16^2 + 16^3 + 16^4 + 16^5 + 16^6` which is equal to `17895697`. I also consider zero being part of the answer, so my range is `0 to 17895697` and therefore, I get `17895698` different values. however, I know that in binary you would do `2^7 = 128`. does it apply to hexadecimals as well? If I do it this way I get `16^7 = 268435456` which does not equal to what I got before.

Is any of my answers correct? if not, could someone please explain what it the right way to do this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be more simple explanation that you would expect, but it does not mean it would not work.

One hexadecimal digit can represent one of 16 values (0x0 to 0xF, or 0 to 15 if you prefer), so 16^7 = 268,435,456 and that's how many different values you can achieve if you use all the bits.

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` to `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

Answer (score 2):

The general formula is the sum of digit * base^place

Consider decimal numbers.  What's the largest number you can represent with 3 decimal digits? The largest possible digit is 9.  Therefore the max number is:
9*10^2 + 9*10^1 + 9*10^0 = 9*100 + 9*10 + 9*1 = 999
The next largest number would with be 1*10^3 = 1000

Another way to calculate the max of decimal three digits, is to get the smallest number with 4 digits and subtract 1.
The smallest decimal with 4 digits is 1000 or
1*10^3 + 0*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 0*10^0 = 1000
Now subtract 1
1000 - 1 =  999

The possible digits for a hex num are 0..F (values 0..15)
For a 7 digits the places range from 6 down to 0.

The largest possible number is therefore:
15*16^6 + 15*16^5 .... 15*16^0

Or the smallest number in hex with 8 digits is #10000000
1*16^7 + 0*16^6 ... + 0*16^0 = 1*16^7
So the largest possible number with in hex with 7 digits is
1*16^7 -1

Answer (score 1):

16^7 is the correct answer. Why? Because for every character you add there are 16 times the previous possibilities. So for 7 characters it's 16^7.

Answer (score 0):

Consider binary - 2^1, you get 0 and 1, 2 possible values.  2^2, you get 0 through 3 (00,01,10,11), 4 possible values.

Using hex, it's 16^7 possible values, which is 268,435,456 possible values.